# pizza problems map value null, handling error

Tags: java

I am trying to check that each element of an array is present in the map. I have done this by using containsKey function. However when it returns null (which I want it to if the toppingChosen isn't in the map) I cannot handle the error. Does anyone know how I could do this please?

```
for(int i = 0; i < toppingsChosen.length; i++)
{
    t.toppings.containsKey(toppingsChosen[i])                   
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do if the chosen topping is not in the map?

Comment: What are you doing with the return value of containsKey?  e.g., what do you want to do if the topping is there?  What about if it's not?

Comment: If it isn't, I need to get the user to choose a different topping because it's not allowed. If the topping is there, I will then get the value of the key in the map and add it to a cost of the pizza

Comment: `containsKey` returns a boolean so it cannot return null. Do you mean 'returns false' or are you actually using `get` which can return null? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this to check if it contains the key, otherwise it's not in your map:

```
if (t.toppings.containsKey(toppingsChosen[i])){
    //do what you want
}

else{
    //not in your map
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Pizza.<init>(Pizza.java:16)
 at PizzaBuild.main(PizzaBuild.java:35)

Comment: What's line 35, then?

Comment: Either `t` is null, or `t.toppings` is null, or `toppingsChosen` is null. How are they initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement will return true or false, if false it goes to the next loop iteration, if true, do whatever processing you need to.

```
for(int i = 0; i < toppingsChosen.length; i++) {
    if (t.toppings.containsKey(toppingsChosen[i])) {
        //do whatever
    } else {
        // not in map, print something, throw an error, 
        // or do nothing and continue (not recommended)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you  just want to skip over the `toppingsChosen[i]` if it is not present in the map(toppings)

You could do something along these lines

```
for(int i = 0; i < toppingsChosen.length; i++)
{
   if (!t.toppings.containsKey(toppingsChosen[i]))    
           continue;// it will just skip the element and loop over the rest of the toppings
    else
//do something useful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use an extended for loop.

```
if (toppingsChosen != null) {
   for (Topping topping : toppingsChosen) {
       if (!t.toppings.containsKey(topping)) {
           // handle missing topping
       } else if (t.toppings.get(topping) == null) {
           // handle error (could be collapsed with upper if branch.)
       }           
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i = 0; i < toppingsChosen.length; i++)
   {

      if( t.toppings!=null){
         if(t.toppings.containsKey(toppingsChosen[i])){
              // value exist in your map
         }else{
             // value not exist in your map
         }
      }
  }
```